# Kubernetes Ingress Flask Application

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kubernetes-service

I have a simple demo Flask application that is deployed to kubernetes using minikube. I am able to access the app using the Services. But I am not able to connect using ingress.

**Services.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: services-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: services-app
  type: ClusterIP             
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000              # External connection
      targetPort: 5000        # Internal connection
```

---

```
D:Path>kubectl get svc
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
db                     ClusterIP   None          <none>        3306/TCP   120m
kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.20.30.1    <none>        443/TCP    3h38m
services-app-service   ClusterIP   10.20.30.40   <none>        5000/TCP   18m
```

**I am able to access the app using minikube.**

```
D:Path>minikube service services-app-service --url
* service default/services-app-service has no node port
* Starting tunnel for service services-app-service.
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME         | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | services-app-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:50759 |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|------------------------|
http://127.0.0.1:50759
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

**Ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: services-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mydemo.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: services-app-service
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

---

```
D:Path>kubectl get ing
NAME               CLASS    HOSTS         ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
services-ingress   <none>   mydemo.info   192.168.40.1   80      15m
```

Are there any additional configuration required to access the app via ingress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **ingress**, and **ingress-dns** addons are currently only supported on **Linux**. Currently not supported on windows.
**[MoreInfo](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues)**

[image]

**Not Supported on Windows**:

- minikube version: v1.16.0
- minikube version: v1.17.1

Comment: That's disappointing - why is this not made more apparent in the documentation? Thanks for your efforts Rakesh!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you need to access it with a Host head of `mydemo.info` for that Ingress spec to work. You also need to confirm you have an Ingress Controller installed, usually ingress-nginx for new users but there are many options. Then you would look for the Ingress Controllers NodePort or LoadBalancer service and access through that.

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried with the host header and get the same `curl: (7) Failed to connect to ........... port 80: Timed out` And ingress controller is installed. I am following instructions from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller

Comment: Unless you have installed MetalLB or similar, it wouldn't be on port 80. Look at the service definition for your ingress controller.

Comment: I tried the very same steps mentioned in the docs. And tried using the same example mentioned in the docs and that also is not working. I believe this is related to https://serverfault.com/questions/1052349/unable-to-connect-to-minikube-ingress-via-minikube-ip

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for ages. I confirm this doesn't work on MacOS either.

Using `minikube tunnel` is the only way I found.